# Coverage failing on Travis but not on local machine - error depends on order of flags

Tags: python, travis-ci, pytest, coverage.py

I'm have the following `script` section in my .travis.yml file:

```
script:
  # run all tests in mymodule/tests and check coverage of the mymodule dir
  # don't report on coverage of files in the mymodule/tests dir itself
  - coverage run -m --source mymodule --omit mymodule/tests/* py.test mymodule/tests -v
```

This works fine on my own (Windows) machine, but throws an error on both Linux and OSX on the Travis build. The error is:

> Import by filename is not supported.

With the flags in a different order I see a different error (only on the Linux build - the OSX tests pass with this order of the flags):

```
-coverage run --source eppy --omit eppy/tests/* -m py.test eppy/tests -v
```

> Can't find '__main__' module in 'mymodule/tests/geometry_tests'

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing from using `coverage` directly to using `pytest-cov`.

```
script:
  # run all tests in mymodule/tests and check coverage of the mymodule dir
  - py.test -v --cov-config .coveragerc --cov=mymodule mymodule/tests
```

And the `.coveragerc` file:

```
# .coveragerc to control coverage.py
[run]
# don't report on coverage of files in the tests dir itself
omit = 
  mymodule/tests/*
```

I don't know why this works where the previous approach didn't, but this at least solves the problem.